# Problem with wrapping of text when using longtable, multicolumn and multirow

Tags: longtable, multicolumn, multirow, wrap

```
\begin{longtable}{p{0.5cm}p{4cm}p{2cm}|p{2cm}p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\cline{4-6}
 &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Percentages and averages} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Nr.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}|}{Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question} & Answers & Pulukan & Tumbak Bayuh & Denpasar \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{23}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Do you know of any organizations that can collect plastic from you? Do you know of any organizations that can collect plastic from you?}} & Yes & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{3-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & No & \% & \% & \% \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

[image]

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcoma to TeX SX! Why all those `\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{...}`?

Comment: I used a table generator, so it was done automatically.  Is there a better way to do this? The last four cells at the lowest row are divided into two rows. Difficult to see with the sentence going out of its cell.

Comment: The code in our question is not compilable, even if I add a documentclass and the relevant packages

Comment: The second argument of `\multicolumn{1}{p{c|}{Question .....}` is wrong. Either you wanted `c` OR `p{some length}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please include a complete, compilable example in your question; it makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: Yes sorry, fixed it! But I have still the same problem with the text wrapping unfortunately

Comment: Regarding: "Is there a better way to do this": First of all, remove all occurences of `\multicolumn{1}{...` since they mostly only clutter your code and are not rally needed. I also recommend to not use automatic table generators, at least not the one you seemed to use since cleanding up such code is often more time consuming thant completely writing it from scratch.

Comment: `\multirow{2}{*}{23} & \multirow{6}{=}{Do you know of any organizations that can collect plastic from you? Do you know of any organizations that can collect plastic from you?} & Yes & \% & \% & \% \\ 
 & & & & & \\
 & & & & & \\ \cline{3-6}
 & & No & \% & \% & \% \\ 
 & & & & & \\
 & & & & & \\ \hline` should give the desired result.

Comment: Since the contents in the second column seem to be very long compared to the other columns, I'd recommend the use a landscape page for your table.

Comment: Wow, yes this works! Thanks. I am only missing the first three verticle line in the last row. Some other verticle lines aswell.

Answer (score 2):

Here is away to do it with a simpler code: I use the `xltabular` environment, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`, so the longtable does not overflows into the margin. I added  `cellspace` , which defines a minimal vertical padding in cells of columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S`(or `C` if you load `siunitx`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array, multirow, bigstrut, cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{6.2ex}
 \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|Sl>{\hsize=1.6\hsize\RaggedRight}S{X}|Sl|*{3}{>{\hsize=0.8\hsize\arraybackslash}X|}}
\cline{4-6}
  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{Sc|}{Percentages and averages} \\ \hline
Nr. & Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question & Answers & Pulukan & Tumbak Bayuh & Denpasar \\ \hline
23 & \smash{\parbox[t]{\hsize}{Do you know of any organizations that can collect plastic from you? Do you know of any organizations that can collect plastic from you?}} & Yes \bigstrut[b] & \% & \% & \% \\ \cline{3-6}
& & No \bigstrut[b] & \% & \% & \% \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for editing, @Zarko!

Comment: `\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}` shifts the text "Do you know..." a little bit down. Could you please explain why you added this piece of code?

Comment: The text is shifted without this \rule – I suspect it is linked with the `S` pre-specifier which works in the following cell, but doesn't work with the `X` column, so I added an invisible rule as a workaround.

Comment: Interesting. I can see a vertical shift in the screenshot you atached. I can also reproduce this shift on my system. If I on the other hand remove the mentioned `\rule`, I get the following that at least to me does not look shifted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxz2i.png

Comment: Finally, I removed the `\multirow` (I think it's the reason why `S` does not work)) and used a smashed `\parbox` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three more suggestions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|l|p{4cm}|l|l|l|l|}
\cline{4-6}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Percentages and averages} \\ \hline
Nr. & Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question & Answers & Pulukan & Tumbak Bayuh & Denpasar \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{23} & \multirow{6}{=}{Do you know of any organizations that can collect plastic from you? Do you know of any organizations that can collect plastic from you?} & Yes & \% & \% & \% \\ 
 & & & & & \\
 & & & & & \\ \cline{3-6}
 & & No & \% & \% & \% \\ 
 & & & & & \\
 & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{longtable}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|l|X|l|l|l|l|}
\cline{4-6}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Percentages and averages} \\ \hline
\thead{Nr.} & \thead{Question} & \thead{Answers} & \thead{Pulukan} & \thead{Tumbak\\ Bayuh} & \thead{Denpasar} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{23} & \multirow{2}{=}{Do you know of any organizations that can collect plastic from you? Do you know of any organizations that can collect plastic from you?} & Yes & \% & \% & \% \\\cline{3-6}
 & & No & \% & \% & \% \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{lXllll}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Percentages and averages} \\ \cmidrule{4-6} 
\thead{Nr.} & \thead{Question} & \thead{Answers} & \thead{Pulukan} & \thead{Tumbak\\ Bayuh} & \thead{Denpasar} \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{23} & \multirow{2}{=}{Do you know of any organizations that can collect plastic from you? Do you know of any organizations that can collect plastic from you?} & Yes & \% & \% & \% \\
 & & No & \% & \% & \% \\ \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```